# Combining multiple across() in a single mutate() sentence, while controlling the variables names in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, across

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(a = 10, b = 20, a_sd = 2, b_sd = 3)

   a  b a_sd b_sd
1 10 20    2    3
```

I want to compute a/a_sd, b/b_sd, and to add the results to the dataframe, and name them ratio_a, ratio_b. In my dataframe I have a lot of variables so I need a 'wide' solution. I tried:

```
df %>% 
  mutate( across(one_of( c('a','b')))/across(ends_with('_sd')))
```

This gave:

```
  a        b a_sd b_sd
1 5 6.666667    2    3
```

So this worked but the new values took the place of the old ones. How can I add the results to the data frame and to control the new names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `.names` argument inside [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html)

```
df %>% 
  mutate(across(one_of(c('a','b')), .names = 'ratio_{col}')/across(ends_with('_sd'))) 
#    a  b a_sd b_sd ratio_a  ratio_b
# 1 10 20    2    3       5 6.666667
```

Comment: Why did you specify the .names argument in the first across() and not in the second one?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know how dplyr operates internally, but it is more intuitive to put it in the first `across`. In fact, the code doesn't return the desired output if you put it in the second `across`